# How to make a program receive the "standard" input from a file if it is launched by the linux command screen?

Tags: linux, shell, command

I used the command `screen` to issue a program `MyProgram` as the following:

`screen -dmL MyProgram`

However, `MyProgram` is supposed to get some inputs from the standard input if it is launched directly without `screen`.  So with `screen`, can I let `MyProgram` obtain the input from a file (as the standard input)? Or is there any other way of bypassing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "any" command when invoking `screen`.  For example

```
screen -dmL sh -c "MyProgram <myFile"
```

will pass the complete command

```
MyProgram <myFile
```

to `screen`.